# How to execute a bash script that use ssh with php

Tags: php, html, linux, bash, ssh

I'd like to execute my script bash with php. My script is logging me into my server then creating me my account.

```
SCRIPT="useradd martinouh --home /home/martinouh --create-home; echo martinouh:$pass | chpasswd; usermod -s /bin/bash martinouh; usermod -aG sudo martinouh; usermod -aG docker martinouh;"

sshpass -p $pass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$ip   "${SCRIPT}"

sshpass -p $pass ssh-copy-id -i /home/Martinouh/.ssh/id_rsa.pub martinouh@$ip
```

But when i run it via `shell_exec();` It does execute the script but not the part with `sshpass`.

What should I do in order to execute it ?

At the moment, just to test `shell_exec();`. I'm executing my script by calling localhost/script.php which contains the following

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec('bash select.sh');
  echo $output;
?>
```

I'm getting this in the error_log :

```
 Failed to change pseudo terminal's permission: Permission denied
 Failed to change pseudo terminal's permission: Permission denied
 Failed to change pseudo terminal's permission: Permission denied
 Failed to change pseudo terminal's permission: Permission denied
```

Maybe it has to do with selinux and apache permission ?

Comment: Does it work as expected when executed the bash script manually?

Comment: Yes it does run as expected when i run it manually.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how are you executing it with php?

Comment: At the moment i'm just executing it by calling localhost/script.php. Which contains <?php $output = shell_exec('bash select.sh');  echo $output ?>

Comment: I think is about user/group of apache try changing it to your user/group, If It works, debian based distros `/etc/apache2/envvars`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now that i've disabled SELinux, it does execute the part that log then add an user ...

But it won't do the

```
sshpass -p $pass ssh-copy-id -i /home/Martinouh/.ssh/id_rsa.pub martinouh@$ip
```

I'm getting this on my webpage

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/Martinouh/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': Permission denied
```

So I tried to move the key and `chown -R apache:apache` on it, what I get was this on my webpage :

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file './id_rsa': No such file or directory (to install the contents of 'id_rsa.pub' anyway, look at the -f option)
```

I tried with the -f but it doesn't change the

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/.pub': No such file or directory
```

edit :

It is now working with SELinux disabled and to correct the ssh-copy-id, I had to copy the id_rsa.pub AND the id_rsa to a directory and `chown -R apache:apache` both of them. The private key was needed otherwise i coudn't copy my id_rsa.pub to the server (even with -f flag).

Now how should I correct this that we know what make it works (even tho it is not the proper way ?)

- Give apache the right to access ~/.ssh/ ? (for ssh-copy-id)
- Give apache the right to execute script / shell ? (SELinux)

Answer (score 0):

Since the error messages refer to the pseudo terminal, try to disable this with -T. Most functionality that require pseudo terminal functionality is interactive and would not be appliccable in such a context anyway.